# rounding a Rails DateTime to the nearest 15 minute interval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to round a `DateTime` and also a `Time` to the nearest 15 minute interval. My thought is to zero out the seconds and the milliseconds (do those exist in a `DateTime` or `Time`?) and maybe even nanoseconds? And then divide the number of minutes by 15, round that, then multiply the result by 15 and set that to be the minutes:

```
# zero out the seconds
time -= time.sec.seconds
# zero out the milliseconds (does that exist?)
# zero out the nanoseconds (less likely this exists)

minutes_should_be = (time.min / 15.to_f).round * 15
time += (minutes_should_be - time.min).minutes
```

So I guess my question is if there is a better way to do this and if milliseconds and nanoseconds exist in a `DateTime` or `Time`? There is a nsec method for nanoseconds, but I think that's the total nanoseconds since epoch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
##
# rounds a Time or DateTime to the neares 15 minutes
def round_to_15_minutes(t)
  rounded = Time.at((t.to_time.to_i / 900.0).round * 900)
  t.is_a?(DateTime) ? rounded.to_datetime : rounded
end
```

The function converts the input to a `Time` object, which can be converted to the seconds since the epoch with `to_i` (this automatically strips nano-/milliseconds). Then we divide by 15 minutes (900 seconds) and round the resulting float. This automatically rounds the time to the nearest 15 minutes. Now, we just need to multiply the result by 15 minutes and convert it to a (date)time again.

#### Example values:

```
round_to_15_minutes Time.new(2013, 9, 13, 0, 7, 0, "+02:00")
#=> 2013-09-13 00:00:00 +0200
round_to_15_minutes Time.new(2013, 9, 13, 0, 8, 0, "+02:00")
#=> 2013-09-13 00:15:00 +0200
round_to_15_minutes Time.new(2013, 9, 13, 0, 22, 29, "+02:00")
#=> 2013-09-13 00:15:00 +0200
round_to_15_minutes Time.new(2013, 9, 13, 0, 22, 30, "+02:00")
#=> 2013-09-13 00:30:00 +0200
round_to_15_minutes DateTime.now
#=> #<DateTime: 2013-09-13T01:00:00+02:00 ((2456548j,82800s,0n),+7200s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: I like the idea of converting to integer to strip milliseconds and nanoseconds

Comment: This doesn't account for time zones.  If `t` is in one time zone, but the local time zone is something else, your hour will change.

Answer (score 4):

A generic rounding solution for DateTime, based on Tessi's answer:

```
class DateTime

  def round(granularity=1.hour)
    Time.at((self.to_time.to_i/granularity).round * granularity).to_datetime
  end

end
```

Example usage:

```
DateTime.now.round 15.minutes
> Fri, 15 May 2015 11:15:00 +0100
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work

```
def nearest15 minutes
  ((minutes / 60.0 * 4).round / 4.0 * 60).to_i
end
```

The idea, is

- get your minutes in terms hours (decimal)
- round to the nearest quarter
- convert back to minutes

---

Some sample output

```
10.times do
  n = [*1..200].sample
  puts "%d => %d" % [n, nearest15(n)]
end
```

Output

```
85 => 90
179 => 180
54 => 60
137 => 135
104 => 105
55 => 60
183 => 180
184 => 180
46 => 45
92 => 90
```

Comment: This is only part of the solution, the part that I did a little simpler in my question.